# Mysterious pink flower planted itself on my balcony

Tags: identification

I live in Western Germany and since this summer a really beatiful flower planted itself on my balcon. I tried finding out what it is but I couldn't come up with a match.

Maybe anybody else has a suggestion? I hope the not-so-well-taken picture will do

[image]

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is *Lychnis coronaria*, also called *Silene coronaria*, also called Rose Campion in English. I like it as a garden plant, but it must be kept dead-headed so that it doesn't seed itself everywhere.